# Como retirar barra do PHPSTorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Boa noite pessoal, tudo bem? Estou com uma duvida no PHPStorm, tem uma barra de navegação que fica a cima do codigo, como removo ela? Segue a foto! Em arquivos js ou css essa bendita barra não aparece, so aparece em arquivos com extensão php e html, como faço pra remove-la?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa 'barra' mostra valores exibe tags html, namespaces, classes, métodos etc quando o curso é deixado dentro de um bloco especifico, para remover vai em:

`File>Settings>Editor>Appearence`

na caixa ao lada direito desmarque a opção:

`show HTML breadcrumps`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado mesmo :)